# execute javascript attached to htmlelement in webbrowser control

Tags: javascript, .net, winforms, browser

I need help on how execute javascript attached to htmlelement in webbrowser control

When typing in an input First textbox, a javascript code execute OnChange for the particular textbox, and display the count of the text in a Second textbox.

But settingvalue using code through the webbrowser, it Second textbox value does not change.

Is there anyway i can execute the javascript after setting value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either call `WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript`, passing in the name of the js function; Or call `HtmlElement.InvokeMember`, passing in the name of the "event" to fire (eg. "OnChange").

EDIT:  Example as requested.

In a button click or DocumentCompleted handler...

```
oWeb.Document.InvokeScript("checkAgree")
```

Comment: thanks for response, but can you give a sample code for this `<input type="checkbox" name="regagree" onclick="checkAgree();" id="regagree" class="check">`